# Android GridView drawing layout

Tags: android, android-layout, gridview, getview

I want to achieve following Image design by using GridView, i have tried with these lines of code but I failed to get blank spaces between 5 and 6, 15 and 16 and so on as it is showing in design.

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

final ViewHolder holder;
View view = convertView;
if (view == null) {

    view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.table_selection_main_item_list,
            parent, false);

    holder = new ViewHolder();
    assert view != null;

    holder.tableSelectionBtn = (TextView) view
            .findViewById(R.id.item_table_selection_btn);
    holder.viewSideSpace = (View) view.findViewById(R.id.view_right_side);

    Log.e("","Table Status ID:::"+tableSelectionList.get(position)
            .getTable_selection_table_status_id()+"Count :: "+getCount());



    if(((position+1)%5==0)&&((position+1)%10==5)){

        gridView.setX(30);
        gridView.setHorizontalSpacing(30);
        holder.viewSideSpace.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.tableSelectionBtn.
        gridView.setColumnWidth(180);
        FrameLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new      FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, FrameLayout
                .LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        layoutParams.leftMargin = 45;
        layoutParams.rightMargin = 45;
        layoutParams.topMargin = 45;
        layoutParams.bottomMargin = 45;


        int size = 150;
        GridLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams=new GridLayout.LayoutParams();
        layoutParams.setMargins(70,70,70,70);

        layoutParams.width=size;
        layoutParams.height=size;
        holder.tableSelectionBtn.sethor//set(0,0,60,0);
        holder.tableSelectionBtn.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

        int pxWidth = (int) (100* Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().density);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams llp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(pxWidth,pxWidth);
        llp.setMargins(0, 0, 40, 0); // llp.setMargins(left, top, right, bottom);

        holder.tableSelectionBtn.setLayoutParams(llp);


    }else{
        //holder.viewSideSpace.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        int pxWidth = (int) (30* Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().density);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams llp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(pxWidth,pxWidth);
        llp.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);  llp.setMargins(left, top, right, bottom);
        holder.tableSelectionBtn.setLayoutParams(llp);
    }



} else {
    holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
}
```

[image]

Comment: and what's the failure exactly ?

Answer (score 0):

1. The solution is very simple,you will have to add just one blank item
   in your data list for getting blank spaces between 5 and 6, 15 and
   16 and so on. Here i am using RecyclerView but you can also use this
   code in your GridView. here is the code.

   ```
   public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

       RecyclerView viewList;
       private GridLayoutManager lLayout;
       int temp=5; 

       @Override
       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
           viewList=(RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);

           ArrayList<String> listInt=new ArrayList<>();
           for(int i=1;i<=80;i++){
               listInt.add(i+"");
               if(temp==i){// logic for adding blank items after 5 elements added
                   temp+=10;
                   listInt.add("");
               }
           }

           lLayout = new GridLayoutManager(MainActivity.this, 11);//no of rows are 11enter image description here
           viewList.setHasFixedSize(true);
           viewList.setLayoutManager(lLayout);

           CircleViewAdapter adapter=new CircleViewAdapter(listInt,this);
           viewList.setAdapter(adapter);

       }
   }

   Adapter code

   public class CircleViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CircleViewAdapter.CircleHolder> {
       private final Context context;
       private List<String> items;

       // Provide a reference to the views for each data item
       // Complex data items may need more than one view per item, and
       // you provide access to all the views for a data item in a view holder
       public class CircleHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
           // each data item is just a string in this case
           public TextView txtView1;

           public CircleHolder(View v) {
               super(v);
               txtView1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView);
           }
       }



       public CircleViewAdapter(List<String> items, Context context) {
           this.items = items;
           this.context = context;
       }

       @Override
       public CircleViewAdapter.CircleHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                              int viewType) {
           View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                   .inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);
           return new CircleHolder(v);
       }

       @Override
       public void onBindViewHolder(CircleHolder holder, int position) {
           String item = items.get(position);
           //TODO Fill in your logic for binding the view.
           holder.txtView1.setText(item);


       }

       @Override
       public int getItemCount() {
           if (items == null) {
               return 0;
           }
           return items.size();
       }
   }
    activiy_main.xml

      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent">
   <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
       android:layout_width="match_parenter code hereent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:id="@+id/recyclerView"/>

   </RelativeLayout>
   ```

   item.xml

   ```
   <TextView
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
       android:text="1"
       android:id="@+id/textView"
       android:layout_margin="5dp"/>
   ```

   [![result][1]][1]

   [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uwMp9.png